# Is EF7 anywhere near usable?

Tags: entity-framework-6, entity-framework-core

All,

Apologies upfront. This may sound a bit like a rant. It probably is. I expected more from the latest (7.0.0-rc1-final) EF7. Any remarks or tips are welcome though!

Feel free to ask about the tables/fields structure, although I hope it will be clear from the naming alone.

My first EF7 query:

```
var enrichedProducts = this.productContext.Products
  .AsNoTracking()
  .Where(p => productNumbers.Contains(p.SAPProductNumber))
  .Select(p => new
    {
      SAPProductNumber = p.SAPProductNumber,
      DisplayName = p.DisplayName,
      Brand = p.Brand,
      Type = p.Type,
      MultimediaValueEpochTime = p.ProductMultimedias
        .Where(pm => pm.Visible == true
                  && pm.ValueEpochTime != null)
        .OrderByDescending(pm => pm.MainItem == true)
        .ThenBy(pm => pm.SortOrder)
        .Select(pm => pm.ValueEpochTime)
        .FirstOrDefault()
    })
  .ToList();
```

This query yields an SqlException: Incorrect syntax near '='.

Cause was the `OrderByDescending(pm => pm.MainItem == true`. `pm.MainItem` is a nullable bit in de database. EF7 translates this into `ORDER BY [pm].[MainItem] = 1 DESC` which SQL Server doesn't like. EF6 translates this quite elaborately but at least it works:

`CASE WHEN (1 = [Extent2].[MainItem]) THEN cast(1 as bit) WHEN ( NOT ((1 = [Extent2].[MainItem]) AND ([Extent2].[MainItem] IS NOT NULL))) THEN cast(0 as bit) END AS [C1]`

and

`ORDER BY [Project1].[C1] DESC`

**But there is something worse!**

After removing `== true` from the `OrderBy`, the query works. To my surprise 9 queries were fired upon SQL Server! It was easy to explain that '9'. There were 8 productnumbers in the `productNumbers` collection. Oh my...

**And worse:** These 8 queries are identical; they don't even have one of the 8 product numbers in their where clauses! Also these 8 queries are not tied to the Products table at all. How strange this all is...

EF6 nicely translates this into 1 query with an `OUTER APPLY` and a `SELECT TOP 1`.

**Attempt to fix:**

Since the entities have been reused from an existing EF6 project, I tried to use fluent instead of annotations where possible. No improvement.

Comment: I think this is useful knowledge.  Have you submitted an issue against EF7. If this question hangs around for years to come, you should include the version of EF7 you are ranting about.

Comment: Good tips. Done both.

Answer (score 0):

This bug has been fixed in the latest codebase, and the fix will be available in RC2

Comment: `productNumbers` is a `List<string>`, not an entity or property. Using Include() seems not applicable to me here. It is the relationship between Product and ProductMultimedia (`p.ProductMultimedias` in the given query) that should have yielded some kind of join.